# Method return data type when using LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have database table `Staff` having the columns `Name`, `Email`, `Address` and `DateOfBirth`. In my web application I have a separate class `ClassMyBase` having a couple of methods. One of the methods uses LINQ to Entities:

```
public static List<Staff> ShowAll()
{
     using (ModelPersonnelContainer myContainer = new 
            ModelPersonnelContainer())
     {
         return myContainer.Staff.ToList();
     }
}
```

... and then in `ButtonShowAll` event handler in `WebForm1`:

```
protected void ButtonShowAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      GridViewAll.DataSource = ClassMyBase.ShowAll();
      GridViewAll.DataBind();
}
```

So far so good, BUT if I add filtering to my `public static List<Staff> ShowAll()`:

```
public static xyz ShowAll()
{
      using (ModelPersonnelContainer myContainer = new 
                ModelPersonnelContainer())
      {
            selectedRrows=from item in myContainer.Staff
                select new
            {
              Name=item.Name,
              Email=item.Email
            }
      }
}
```

my method won’t work because the return data type is no more same as previously. Any easy solutions? What could this return data type `xyz` be?

If I put everything together (no separate class in my project) and have only `ButtonShowAll` it will work all right, so like this:

```
protected void ButtonShowAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            using (ModelPersonnelContainer myContainer = new 
            ModelPersonnelContainer())
            {
                var selectedRows = from item in myContainer.Staff
                                  select new
                                  {
                                    Name=item.Name,
                                    Email=item.Email
                                  };
                GridView1.DataSource = selectedRows.ToList();
                GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: You can use `List<dynamic>` as your type

Comment: you need to add the `.ToList()` after the filtering in your static method to return a list of staff

Answer (score 1):

This part of your code creates an anonymous class:

```
new
{
    Name=item.Name,
    Email=item.Email
}
```

You should name it explicitly, then that class name will be used, and you can type your return type:

```
new Staff()
{
    Name=item.Name,
    Email=item.Email
}
```

Additionally, you might want to use `ToList()`, or change your return type to `IEnumerable<Staff>`, since the LINQ query will not return a `List<Staff>`:

```
var selectedRows = ...
                   .ToList();
```

Comment: This is better than my proposed `dynamic` solution. One could argue that you might be better off with a `StaffViewModel` class to bind to. Then you can add view specific rules to that class.

Comment: @Timpe: need more help?